# How do you disable the seekbar in a media controller?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I would like to disable the seekbar but keep the pause and play buttons in a media controller object. I don't want users to be able to skip through the video, but they can pause if needed.

I've looked at other questions like this but they didn't make sense to me. If I could get any help on this that would be great!

Comment: what exactly have you tried?

Comment: Provide your code to audience.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
seekbar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
     }
    });
```

Comment: How do you access the seekbar within the media controller? (your seekbar variable)

Comment: you don't need to access seekbar in media controller, use the above code in your onCreate. Declare seekbar object in your class and define the seeker view in your onCreate using findViewById.

Answer (score 0):

In the `MediaController` there are two methods that return a boolean: `canSeekBackward()` and `canSeekForward()`. I think if you set these to return `false` then the user will not be able to seek.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.MediaPlayerControl.html#canSeekBackward%28%29